# Incorporating two variables to one with changing values in R

Tags: r

I was trying to make a new variable, with following V265 and V267.

Putting 0 on V267 when the value has two digits, don't put 0 when it is three digits / and cutting any front 0 of V265 (like row 5). Then incorporate fixed V265 and V267 to a new variable.

I tried bunch of codes and googled but I couldn't make it. Thanks in advance!

```
    V265   V267          New
 1   26    55        -> 26055
 2   36    61        -> 36061
 3   36    71        -> 36071
 4   47    125       -> 47125
 5   06    37        -> 6037
 6   42    81        -> 42081
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df$New <- 1000*df$V265+df$V267
```

Answer (score 1):

More general and more typing than @josilber's answer:

```
as.numeric(paste0(df$V265,
       formatC(df$V267, format = "d", width = 3, flag = "0")))
```